# How do I import my custom class correctly into this FXML file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm making a simple cookbook app to practice JavaFX and I'm running into a problem. I can't seem to import this class:

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Recipe {
   private final SimpleStringProperty Name = new SimpleStringProperty("");

   public Recipe() {
        this("");
    }

    public Recipe(String recipeName) {
        setRecipeName(recipeName);

    }

    public String getRecipeName() {
        return Name.get();
    }

    public void setRecipeName(String rName) {
        Name.set(rName);
    }

}
```

Into this FXML view file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import fxmltableview.*?>
<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import application.Recipe ?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TableView prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="599.0" text="Column One" >
          <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="Name" />
         </cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
        </columns>
        <items>
    <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
        <Recipe Name="Test Name"/>
    </FXCollections>
        </items>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I keep getting an error on the  line. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,

I don't know, if that fixes your problem (I think not, sry), but naming your variable "Name" (first letter upper case) is considered bad style and could be misinterpreted by the compiler. (At least as far as I know...)

Comment: Yeah, that didn't really help me, but you're right and I changed it to recipeName, which is more distinct, but...I still can't get it to work. Edit: Nevermind, it was the naming convention. Name apparently refers to a reserved field in...something, I don't know, but it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property names in Java are determined by the method names, not the field names. Since your `Recipe` class defines methods `getRecipeName()` and `setRecipeName(...)`, the property name is `recipeName`. Consequently you need

```
 <Recipe recipeName="Test Name"/>
```

You can name the field anything you like - it won't affect what the property name is considered to be. However, it is good practice to follow [standard naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java) and make field names begin lower case. It's also useful in JavaFX to define a property accessor method. Here is an example:

```
public class Recipe {
   private final SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");

   public Recipe() {
        this("");
    }

    public Recipe(String recipeName) {
        setRecipeName(recipeName);

    }

    public String getRecipeName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setRecipeName(String rName) {
        name.set(rName);
    }

    public StringProperty recipeNameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as it turns out I can't name the fields "Name", because it apparently refers to something in FXCollections (I think), so I changed my property to recipeName and that seems to solve the problem.

Comment: A like would be nice ;)

Comment: That's not the problem at all. The issue is that the property name in the class is `recipeName` (because you have `getRecipeName` and `setRecipeName`) methods, but in the FXML you are trying to reference a property called `Name` (so the FXMLLoader will try to find a method called `setName`, which doesn't exist).